# Email field is displaying as [email protected] from google sheets =importhtml() function

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

is there any way to disable this? I am hosting the table I am grabbing info from

all other info is displaying correctly btw

Comment: From where are you importing the info and specifically the email address?

Comment: @ziganotschka I am creating a table using the stripe API. It is hosted on my bluehost shared server. I also tried using =importxml() but I got the same results

Comment: Sounds like the problem is related to your data / the way it is stored on your server, rather than Sheets.

Comment: @ziganotschka its probably some sort of protection from the stripe api, i decided to create a script that exports a sheets upload ready file instead of doing =importhtml()

Answer (score 1):

It is a feature of Google Sheets and the **=importhtml()** function.  It seems any @ symbol in the source HTML is replaced by **[email protected]**.

I was importing a timetable where "**2.30 a.m.@** " rendered as "**2.30 [email protected]** " in my sheet (the @ was marker for a footnote).

I could not find a way to disable it so resolved it by duplicating the table and using the **=SUBSTITUTE()** function to change it back.

```
    =SUBSTITUTE(H7,"[email protected]","@")
```

Comment: I needed to get a list of emails created from a database exported to csv. I was able to mitigate this by using the function =IMPORTDATA('https://mysite.site/my-csv-export.php')

this made sheets download the file and read locally which resolved the [email protected] error.